# clearTimeout not working using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function ShowProgress1() {
                var timerid;
                timerid=setTimeout(function () {
                    var modal = $('<div />');
                    modal.addClass("modal1");
                    $('body').append(modal);
                    var loading = $(".loading1");
                    loading.show();
                    var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                    var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                    loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
                    test();
                }, 0);
            }
            //hide
            function test() {
                if (timerid != null) {
                    clearTimeout(timerid);
                }
            }
            $('[id*=chk_ColorCL]').live("click", function () {
                ShowProgress1();
            });
    </script>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chk_ColorCL" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                                                                                                                                RepeatColumns="25" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="fun_chkColor" AutoPostBack="true">                                                                                                                       </asp:CheckBoxList>

    private void funchk()
    {
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "test()", true);
    }
```

here

> i want to show the image after alert is executed the image will be
>   disappeared

but not working.I mentioned my code sample above.

Comment: This isn't a C# or ASP.Net question.

Answer (score 2):

The `timerId` variable that you are referencing in `test`method is different than the one referenced in `ShowProgress1`. Here is why: when declaring `var timerid` inside `ShowProgress1` you are making that variable local to the scope of the function so it is not available outside of it.

Move the declaration of the `timerId` variable out of `ShowProgress1` method so both methods make reference to the same variable.

```
var timerid;

function ShowProgress1() {
    timerid=setTimeout(function () {
      var modal = $('<div />');
      modal.addClass("modal1");
      $('body').append(modal);
      var loading = $(".loading1");
      loading.show();
      var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
      var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
      loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
      test();
  }, 0);
}
    //hide
function test() {
    if (timerid != null) {
        clearTimeout(timerid);
    }
}
$('[id*=chk_ColorCL]').live("click", function () {
    ShowProgress1();
});
```

Comment: I would always encourage to use parameters instead global variables, indeed use anything before global variables.